# Java Reading in Images

Tags: java, image

I was reading in images that were in the same folder as my programs like this

```
public void GetImages() {
    imgMonster = new ImageIcon(Astro_n_Monster.class.getResource("image.png")).getImage();
   }
```

but now I've moved them into a different folder but within the project folder still.  I'm not quite sure how to read them anymore because I've tried stuff like, "H:NetBeansProjects\Game\Pictures\image.png" but that won't read it in.  I need help with what to change within the ""

Comment: What is Astro_n_Monster class?

Comment: Some painting, some moving, some animating, everything I've been working on xD

Comment: what Exception is thrown

Comment: Is your image stored in the same package where your Astro_n_Monster class is placed or somewhere else ??

Comment: There is no exception thrown yet and the image is in a folder within project but not the package.  I was told to have only java files in the package so I cannot move them there.

Comment: If you are allowed to move images in package structure then i have posted a simple solution. But if not then your need to used the absolute path Answer posted by Sergi might be the answer. You just need to recheck your code and path. If your path contains spaces then your need to escape the double code in beginning and end of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
imgMonster = new ImageIcon("Pictures/image.png").getImage();
```

You can call it without using `getResource()`.  If you juse use this file path, it should work.  Netbeans will start from the Game dir Which is your project root. From there it will follow your file path specified

```
Game (project root) 
    Pictures
           image.png
    src
    build
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **H:\\NetBeansProjects\\Game\\Pictures\\image.png** or **H:/NetBeansProjects/Game/Pictures/image.png**. The char "\" is only for escaping other characteres. And your code is wrong. It should be like this:

```
Image imgMonster = new ImageIcon("H:\\NetBeansProjects\\Game\\Pictures\\image.png").getImage();
```

Comment: Then there is something else wrong. Can you post all your code?

Comment: The only thing that was wrong line that I was reading the image from @Sergi and I think my code is too long to post anyways xD. I tried using all the forms of slashes

Answer (score 0):

`AnyClass.class.getResource("image.png")` returns the absolute URL of that resource. But for that it must be located into the class path folder.

For your code to work, `image.png` should be available where the `.class` file of `Astro_n_Monster` generates.

Comment: Thanks for that but that is how I had images before I was told to move them out of the location of the class

Answer (score 0):

Consider following package structure with simple solution for loading image from package

```
com
  |_ myCompany
     |_ images
        |_ image.png
com
  |_ myCompany
      |_ javaClasses
         |_ Astro_n_Monster
```

Now even your move your class Astro_n_Monster class along with images package you will get the output using following code

```
imgMonster = new ImageIcon(Astro_n_Monster.class.getResource("/com/myCompany/images/image.png")).getImage();
```

Comment: Wouldn't I just have "H:\\NetBeansProjects\\Game\\Pictures\\image.png" like @Sergi suggested?  Because if so then that still doesn't work.